# Adding Google Chrome to Safari for Windows "Develop"

Tags: windows, google-chrome, safari

The Safari for Windows *Develop* menu has the item *Open Page with ...*, but the only choice is Internet Explorer.  I want to be able to use Google Chrome.  How does Safari for Windows decide what to put on this menu, and how to I get Google Chrome onto the list?

Answer (score 1):

It **should** show Google Chrome in the *Open Page with...* menu item.

I have installed Safari for Windows 5.0.2 and it correctly displays **all my other browsers** (Google Chrome, Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox, in this instance).

What versions of Safari and Chrome are you using?